# Can I ignore the type of Either Right if I'm ignoring the value?

Tags: haskell

I have an IO action that runs the following pattern three times in a row:

```
runAction :: IO a -> IO Bool
runAction action = do
  result <- action
  case result of
    Right _ -> return True
    _ -> return False

callingFunc :: IO Bool
callingFunc = do
  resA <- runAction a
  resB <- runAction b
  resC <- runAction c
  return (resA && resB && resC)


a :: IO (Either ByteString Integer)
b :: IO (Either ByteString ByteString)
c :: IO (Either ByteString Bool)
```

This works fine, but I'd like to eliminate some redundancy. This doesn't work because of the type of the Right side of Either:

```
  {-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

  import Control.Monad
  import Data.ByteString.Char8 as BSC 


  runAction :: Bool -> IO (Either ByteString a) -> IO Bool
  runAction prev action = do
    result <- action
    case result of
      Right _ -> return prev
      _ -> return False


  actA :: IO (Either ByteString Integer)
  actA = return (Right 1)


  actB :: IO (Either ByteString Bool)
  actB = return (Right True)


  main :: IO ()
  main = do
    res <- foldM runAction True [actA, actB]
    print res
```

Resulting error:

```
Actions.hs:25:38:
    Couldn't match type ‘Bool’ with ‘Integer’
    Expected type: IO (Either ByteString Integer)
      Actual type: IO (Either ByteString Bool)
    In the expression: actB
    In the third argument of ‘foldM’, namely ‘[actA, actB]’
```

But I never actually look at the value. I just check if I got Right or not.

Is there any way for me to hide or ignore the type of the Right of Either? Is there a better or more idiomatic way to reduce or abstract this?

EDIT: Sorry, must have pasted an old copy of code. Updated.

Comment: The code you posted is not the code that appears in your error message.  Are you sure you've posted the right code?  Also, `return prev && True` won't work, you're looking for `return $ prev && True`, which is equivalent to just `return prev`

Comment: You could also simplify it a bit with just `return $ either (const False) (const prev) result` instead of the case statement.

Comment: And this works for me: `foldM (\prev action -> either (const prev) (const False) <$> action) True [return (Right 1), return (Left "2"), return (Right 3)]`, which should be equivalent to what you have.  I will point out that your `runAction` function should have the type `Bool -> IO (Either a b) -> IO Bool` instead.

Comment: @bheklilr Your example isn't quite the same as what I'm trying to do. I want my runAction to ignore the type of Right. So the second item in the list would be `return (Right "2")` i.e.: `foldM (\prev action -> either (const prev) (const False) <$> action) True [return (Right 1), return (Right "2"), return (Right 3)]` which throws an error.

Comment: The problem there is your list, not your `runAction`.  You can't mix `Either a Int` and `Either a String` in a list, or even `IO (Either a Int)` and `IO (Either a String)`, all lists are homogeneous.

Comment: Although you are correct that my example is incorrect, just that it should have been `foldM (\prev action -> either (const False) (const prev) <$> action) True`, I got the arguments to `either` in the wrong order.

Comment: Note that a simpler definition for `runAction` is just `fmap isRight`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem comes from the types of `actA` and `actB` being in the same list.  Lists in Haskell are homogenous, you can't mix elements of different types.  `actA` and `actB` have explicitly different types, there's no possible way for the types to be unified.  You can't have the type `[Either a1 b1, Either a2 b2]`, this sort of thing just doesn't exist (without a lot of extensions and type system magic, anyway).

Comment: I see how `foldM` over a list won't work per your answer, but is there another pattern I could use that would allow me to reduce this code? All I want to do is perform an arbitrary number of these actions without the bookkeeping. The type will always be `IO (Either ByteString a)` but the `a` can be pretty much any type...

Comment: @ChrisHanson Where are the values coming from? You can't really have a heterogeneous list in the first place in Haskell (without some tricky stuff). If you just want to ignore the `Right` values, you could make them all the same type with `void` (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:void ).

Comment: Why use `Either` and not `Maybe`?

Comment: The actions I want to chain all come from a third party library (namely hedis) which uses `Either`. I'm actually interested in the value if it's on the `Left`, but if it's on the `Right`, I don't actually care what's in there.

Comment: @ChrisHanson Your best bet is probably to use `Data.Either.isRight` and `fmap` to convert the types for you, then you can `fmap and . sequence` to fold over your list of `IO Bool`s.